# Error trying to import a JSON file in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoimport

So I'm getting this in my command terminal when I try to import the following file:

```
    C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport --db test --collection horse_data --file horse1.json
2016-02-23T20:31:18.731-0500    connected to: localhost
2016-02-23T20:31:18.736-0500    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'h' in literal Timestamp (expecting 'i')
2016-02-23T20:31:18.743-0500    imported 0 documents
```

With the following horse1.json file (Which I'm not entirely certain is correctly written, I've got very little experience with JavaScript:

```
{
    _horse_name:"Seabiscuit",
    _horse_gender:"Male",
    _breed:"Thoroughbred",
    _weight:1199,
    _date_of_birth:"May 23, 1933",
    _sire:"Hard Tack",
    _mare:"Swing On",
    _auction_price:104260
}
```

I'm honestly stumped here. Any pointers?

Comment: There are no "quotes" around any of the key names. That means it is not valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/). JavaScript objects don't require quoted keys, but JSON does. You will need to convert the source data. I'd suggest `sed` or `awk` on a Unix system, or similar script. You can even then just "pipe" the output into the `mongoimport` command. I'd also advise changing the "date" data into valid date objects. See [MongoDB extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_date) for the format you should be using.

Comment: That solved it! Wow talk about a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks!